# Android resourcenotfoundexception non-activity class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

При следующем коде вызывается ошибка resourcenotfoundexception. Если писать а Activity `var bordergrid =  ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.border, null)` к  примеру в onCreate такой ошибки нет.

```
class StyleChanger{
            object companion {
                    val TAG  = "Style companion"

                    var bordergrid : Drawable? =   null

                    init {
                            try {
                                   bordergrid =  ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(Resources.getSystem() ,R.drawable.border , null)
                            }
                            catch (e : Exception) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
                            }
                    }
            }

    }
```

Я сделал так :

```
class StyleChanger {
        object companion {
                val TAG  = "Style companion"

                var bordergrid: Drawable? =   null

                fun yellowstyle(res : Resources ){

                     bordergrid = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(res, R.drawable.borderyellow, null)
            }
        }
}
```

При создании моей главной Activity инициилизирую поле bordergrid `StyleChanger.companion.bordergrid =  ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources() ,R.drawable.border , null)` . А если хочу его поменять, то вызываю метод yellowstyle , в который передаю resources из Activity или Fragment.

Comment: Resources.getSystem() возвращает системные ресурсы, а не ресурсы приложения.

Comment: Если переделать так : ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources() , R.drawable.border , null) , то  getResources()  - unresolved reference

Comment: Вполне логично -- в классе StyleChanger нет приведенного метода.